# YQ update style of key/value attribute

Tags: yq

On YQ v4, i would need to transform a yaml file like:

```
test:
  A: "customData"
  B: 123
```

Into a .env format :

```
A="customData"
B=123
```

I have come up with this command:

```
yq '.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + .value"' ./input.yaml > ./.env
```

Unfortunatly, quotes disapear in the output with this command.
Earlier YQ version had a `tostring` built-in function, but not it is not working anymore apparently wit v4.
I have tried style="double" without any success so far.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Earlier YQ version had a `tostring` built-in function, but not it is not working anymore apparently wit v4.

You seem to be confusing [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq). While the former (currently on version 4.40.5) is heavily inspired by jq but has its own DSL that never included `tostring`, the latter (currently on version 3.2.2) actually uses jq under the hood which of course did and still does have `tostring`.

Yet, neither jq's `tostring` (available in kislyuk's yq), nor styling with `style="double"` or converting with `tag="!!str"` (both available in mikefarah's yq) would automatically wrap strings into double quotes. Note that quotes could easily be added using `… + "\"" + …` (yet, selectively applying that to only strings would be quite different for the two implementations), but in the end you most probably want more than just quotes around strings anyway, as you likely want to properly encode the value part (for instance, you probably want to somehow escape quotes that were already part of the data).

And that proper encoding is the key to your solution. You could, for example, use the `tojson` or `@json` encoders (supported by kislyuk/yq since the beginning (as its introduction into jq predates kislyuk/yq), and by mikefarah/yq since [version 4.14.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.14.1) as `tojson` and since [version 4.16.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.16.1) as `@json`), which both provide you with double quotes on strings while leaving numbers as is.

```bash
# works with all versions of kislyuk/yq, and with mikefarah/yq 4.16.1+
.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @json)

# works with all versions of kislyuk/yq, and with mikefarah/yq 4.14.1+
# but note that with mikefarah/yq, additional empty lines are added
.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | tojson)
```

```json
A="customData"
B=123
```

Note, however, that it is not obvious from your sample how you want other (esp. edge-)cases to be handled, and whether all the aspects of this JSON-encoding (e.g. escaping double quotes in strings with backslash, removing insignificant whitespace from the formatting of arrays and objects, etc.) actually do fit your use-case. In fact, as you are writing the output into a file called `.env`, I'd guess that you want the output to be subsequently interpreted by a shell. For POSIX shells, you could, for example, use the `@sh` encoder instead (supported by kislyuk/yq since the beginning (as its introduction into jq predates kislyuk/yq), and by mikefarah/yq since [version 4.31.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.31.1)). This way, you are guaranteed to get a valid encoding that can always be interpreted by the shell, but both implementations prefer using single quotes over double quotes for strings (making the encoding less noisy on special characters like `$` as they don't require escaping).

```bash
# works with kislyuk/yq
.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | @sh)
```

```bash
A='customData'
B=123
```

The mikefarah/yq implementation even limits the quoting to where the shell requires their presence, which eventually might (and does indeed in this case) lead to the complete omission of quotes. Also, as the `@sh` encoder of this implementation only processes strings, a conversion to `!!str` using `tag` or `type` becomes necessary.

```bash
# works with mikefarah/yq 4.31.1+, but needs conversion to !!str first
.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | . type = "!!str" | @sh)
```

```bash
A=customData
B=123
```

But even with this shell-oriented encoding, you'd still need to determine whether it fits your use-case for data types other than those shown in your sample (e.g. kislyuk/yq would convert arrays into space-separated strings but refuse the conversion of objects altogether, while mikefarah/yq would simply produce the empty string when the iterable types `!!seq` and `!!map` are being converted into `!!str`).

Comment: Thanks you so much for this detailled answer.
You were right. I did not know there was two yq versions.
My final solution is two use both :D. I have renamed `mikefarah/yq` as yq2 to do yaml merge files and yq to output as .env file

Btw, I  have added the -r option (raw) in order to have the expected result.

With `kislyuk/yq`, I have used the command below :
`yq -r '.test | to_entries | .[] | .key + "=" + (.value | tostring)'` 

And yes, my data are more complex so @json was not a fit for me.
Thank you again for the explanation.

Comment: You're very welcome! Yes, for kislyuk/yq (like with jq) you'd need the `--raw-output` (or `-r`) flag, and for mikefarah/yq prior to version 4.18.1 you'd need the `eval` (or `e`) command to produce the expected output. Also, while `@json` and `@sh` are implemented in both, mikefarah/yq can also produce so-called "properties strings". Try out `yq2 '.test | @props' input.yaml` or `yq2 -op '.test' input.yaml`, and see if that fits your use-case.